# if statement executes code under wrong condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a simple code with a `if` statement as follows:

```
if ((marker.category == str || $("#type").length === 0)
    && (marker.session == session || session.length === 0)) {
  marker.setVisible(true); 
  console.log("session"+session);  
} else if (marker.session == session || session.length === 0) {
  marker.setVisible(true); 
} else {
  marker.setVisible(false);
  infowindow.close(map, marker1);
}
```

If I run this code, it always executes the `else if` condition, but I think the `if` and `else if` conditions are different, how to solve this problem? I know the `if` and `else if` may have a part of same conditions but with operator `&&` it should be different, right? It has really confused me.

Comment: What's with the trailing `}` curly bracket in the end? It closes nothing.

Comment: I think your this part `marker.session == session || session.length === 0` is true in first if condition but first one not that's why its going to else if

Comment: You are doing the same action for your first 2 cases.

Comment: i just copy paste from my all code, in up that code i have other code for that bracket, thanks for you notice :)

Comment: If your _"else if"_ condition is being evaluated as true, it means that `(marker.category == str || $("#type").length === 0)` must be `false` in your first `if` condition. I'm not really sure how this is not clear

Comment: @Phil and @ArunKumar have given a very logically right view about this. Unless @Kraken is sure that `(marker.category == str || $("#type").length === 0)` is definitely `true`, nothing else could possibly be causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite odd to repeat part of a logical *AND* in an `else if` condition. I feel you may be able to understand this better if you refactor the common parts out.

For example

```
if (marker.session == session || session.length === 0) {
  marker.setVisible(true); // same for first two conditionals
  if (marker.category == str || $("#type").length === 0) { // &&
    console.log("session", session);
  }
} else {
  marker.setVisible(false);
  infowindow.close(map, marker1);
}
```

If you don't see that `console.log()`, it clearly means the

```
marker.category == str || $("#type").length === 0
```

expression is evaluating as `false`.

---

You could even simplify this further by re-using the same boolean values where required. This can eliminate the `else` blocks which can aid readability. I also think it's odd to conditionally log something so just log it anyway.

```
let sessionVisible = marker.session == session || session.length === 0
marker.setVisible(sessionVisible)
console.log("session", session);
if (!sessionVisible) {
  infowindow.close(map, marker1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (marker.session == session || session.length == 0) {
    marker.setVisible(true);
    if (marker.category == str || $("#type").length == 0) { 
        console.log("session"+session);
    } else {   }
} else {
    marker.setVisible(false);
    infowindow.close(map, marker1);
}
```

Comment: You should probably clean-up that dangling `else { }`

Answer (score 0):

this is solved, with this code

```
 if ( (marker.session == session || session.length === 0) && (marker.category == str)){
                   marker.setVisible(true); 


           }else if( (marker.session == session || session.length === 0)  && (str.length === 0)){


               marker.setVisible(true); 

           }else {
               marker.setVisible(false);
               infowindow.close(map, marker1);
           }
       }
```

that is seem like same condition but different, thanks for you all to help me